# Firefox height issue

Tags: css

I am building a website that is heavily dependent on bootstrap modal windows. And it works fine in Chrome, Safari, and miraculously IE, but for some reason it seems to be messing up in Firefox on both Windows and Mac.

I have a set height in the modal content so that the modal fits most of the page, like so

```
.largeModal div.modal-content.padded {
    height: 90%;
}
```

and then the `iframe` within has a height on it as well

```
largeModal iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Both heights are ignored in Firefox and the window being rendered so small that you can't read anything inside it. Is there anyway to fix this?

So far I have tried setting the heights as `pixies` and `ems` as well, but that doesn't seem to help. I have also tried `max-height` and `min-height`, but those are ignored as well.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `height: 100%` to the `body` itself? I've had this issue with Firefox in the past and that fixed it.

Comment: To the iframe body? Yes, I have it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Try placing the `!important` after the values.

Comment: Setting the height as `pixies` isn't going to get you very far...

Comment: @bodi0 I did put !important after the heights.

Comment: @zazvorniki I meant to the body of the main page the iFrame is displayed in.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar That was why I was using percents or ems. I was just trying pixels to see if anything would work.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker I have an overall style that calls all the body's and that is at 100%

Comment: I think some actual html might help here. Can you replicate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net ? And I think mikeTheLiar was only making a small joke about the fact you used the word `pixies` instead of `pixels`.

Comment: @zaz you have a typo. pixies != pixels.

Comment: @anothershrubery I would have to post my entire website here (I can't do this I'm in a company environment) to show the html and the same applies with the fiddle

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Sorry, auto correct got me. You knew what I meant though. :)

Comment: You don't need to post any content whatsoever. Just try to replicate the issue in a fiddle with as little coding as possible. Without something to work off it's going to be guesswork. Also, in trying to replicate the issue by producing a minimised fiddle, you might actually work out what the issue is yourself.

Comment: @anothershrubery To replicate this issue I would reveal too much about this company in a fiddle. There is no way around that, it's a bootstrap modal loading external content within an iframe. I can't replicate it without that external page and I have tried multiple times in the past to get a fiddle working with this kind of content for a separate issues, but it just would not work because of the remote content.

Comment: Well then we are back to guessing territory, I'm sure there would be ways to replicate these issues but if you're not going to try... 1) May be a typo, but you have `largeModal iframe` instead of `.largeModal iframe` 2) Try wrapping the `iframe` in a div and resizing that instead of the `iframe` We can't possibly put forward an "answer" without any html structure so this is the best we can do.